# Tools jar does not exist Eclipse JAVA

Tags: eclipse, java

`The archive: C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_26-32/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.`

This is the error I have when run Tomcat. There was no problem cleaning or publishing - only when i start the Tomcat server.

Now, I checked my folders and there is a `tools.jar` in file path `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib`

What am i missing?

using jre6 and have jdk1.6.0_34 installed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click on your eclipse project, In `Preferences` go to `Java > Installed JREs, select your JDK` and click on `Edit`. In the new Dialog you can **add external jars** like `tools.jar` to your execution environment.

Comment: I doubt this is a good solution, especially when he mixes JARs from different Java versions.

Comment: I think you should empasize the word ``JDK``, I had JRE already there so confused a little.

Comment: It only worked for me after selecting "run as"->"Ant Build..."->"JRE"->"Run in the same JRE as the workspace". I also added the tools.jar, as in the answers, but I had to do this one more step.

Comment: I'm using maven for projects, I don't think so we need to add the external jar, although that will work but not the good idea, only issue is eclipse is not pointing to JDK currently, it is pointing to JRE, just change JRE to JDK, and that's it, that will start working.

Answer (score 31):

I found this question trying to build my project using Ant in Eclipse, and I would get the same error message as above. The suggestions in @Parth's and other answers to edit the Installed JREs is the first step. What I also needed to run Ant successfully was

1. Right click on build.xml, select "Run As", select "Ant Build..." (note the ...)
2. Click on the JRE tab
3. Change the Runtime JRE to the same thing that you updated in the first stage, and press Apply. (That is, the runtime JRE as you specified by "Preferences" -> "Java" -> "Installed JREs", as in @Parth's answer.)

Otherwise it seems that Ant will still try to build with the old JRE that doesn't have `tools.jar`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: What do you mean `to the same thing that you updated in the first stage`?

Comment: the installed JRE as specified in Parth's answer. I have updated my own answer to be more clear on this.

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution to resolve this.

Go to Run Configurations > classpath and under User Enteries you will have tools.jar and its path would be pointing to the old folder. Remove that and click on "Add External Jars" to add the tools.jar from the new path. And that is it.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Eclipse:

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Select Java -> Select Installed JREs -> Add 
-> Add your JDK -> Establish it as default -> Apply -> OK.
```

After this, I've to establish project related settings too:

```
Right click on your Project Name (in Project explorer ) -> Properties ->
Java Build Path -> Click on JRE System Libraries -> Edit -> 
Select Workspace Default JRE (jdk included above)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your "run configurations" (Eclipse Menu Run -> Run Configurations ....) also, since therein the classpath may be wrong or has gotten obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat needs a full JDK/SDK to run but under `C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_26-32/`, you only have a JRE installed.

Cleaning and deploying is done by Eclipse, no Tomcat code is involved so this works.

You need to configure your environment so that Tomcat uses `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34` as Java VM. Check the values of `JAVA_HOME` and the content of `setenv.bat`

Comment: does it matter that i am using `jre6`? also when i call `echo %JAVA_HOME$` i get `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34`

Comment: Who says "The archive: C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_26-32/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist."? Eclipse? Tomcat? Do you see it in a log file or the command line?

Comment: Changing the jre path to jdk fixed this issue. Even referencing as external jar doesn't solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project->Properties->Compiler->Configure workspace settings->go to configure->installed jre->give jdk path

Answer (score 1):

In my case with using ANT build I had to change the setting
Add tools.jar in the below location.
 Windows --> Preferences --> Ant --> Runtime --> Global Entries.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Tomcat server in Eclipse has been created under older JDK (just a few builds). My solution was to remove the sever and add it again (now using current JDK).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I can reproduce it) and my solution sounds like the integration in Eclipse is really screwed up but I actually fixed it by starting Eclipse with the same JDK version.

Add/edit the following in your *eclipse.ini* (which is in the Eclipse directory):

```
-vm
path/to/jdk/bin
```

Where *path/to/jdk/bin* is the path to the JDK bin directory of the version you are using for ant/tomcat.

Note that tools.jar is NOT included in a JRE distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ant build file and getting this error in eclipse, then your eclipse is configured to use two differently named JRE's. i.e. One from the jre folder and another jre from inside the jdk's folder. Adding `tools.jar` may be a workaround but I used the JRE inside the JDK's folder(`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`). Inorder to change this,

1. Check in Installed JRE section which JRE is cheked(I had `jdk1.8.0_121` checked and `jre1.8.0_121` left unchecked).
2. Update your eclipse classpath by navigating to `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE > Execution Environments`.
3. Now select the `JavaSE-1.x` on the left side and select the compatible JRE[perfect match]. Select the same JRE(`jdk1.8.0_121`) you had it checked above and click Ok. Optionally you can delete the JRE(jre1.8.0_121) which is unused to avoid confusion if it is not used in any other projects.

Now your project will build and you can run the Ant build files. Check the image below.

[image: Eclipse Installed JRE configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the tools.jar as an external JAR.

For eclipse,

1. Right click the project name and select Properties
2. Go to Java "Build Path"
3. Select tab "Libraries"
4. Click "Add External JARs"
5. Select the relevant .jar file from the file selection

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it applies to all situations, but if you right click Ant script and there is an item "External tools configuration" under "Run as" menu, select it, and go to JRE tab. As far as I can say, it may be configured independently from your project and point to the JRE, not JDK, in which case there would be missing tools.jar

Answer (score 0):

I remove server (Tomcat 6.0) from window -> preferences -> server -> Runtime environment.
And add again. Then, I add my project to server again. The problem is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If You are getting this error while running the ANT build then follow the below steps.
In the Eclipse go-to window-> preferences-> ANT-> RUNTIME
then select classpath tab then select Global Entries and add `tools.jar` as an `external jar`.

Run the ANT build.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project->
Properties->
Java Build Path->
Libraries->
Add Library->
JRE System Library->
Choose Alternate JRE->
Click Installed JREs->
Click Add->
select Jdk path from program files
click on jdk checkbox then Apply and close