# missing tools.jar error on Update Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

When i try to update maven project I get the error that maven cant find tools.jar in JRE locations shown below:
[image]
 However I have installed and specefied JDK in Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE.
Is there any other place the JDK should be specified in order to resolved this tools.jar issues.

Note: tools.jar is located in lib of JDK_HOME directory and i also specified the jar as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641849/tools-jar-does-not-exist-eclipse-java) answer but it did not resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to pom.xml and then:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```